# Method invocation may produce java NullpointerException .setText()

Tags: android

I am just a beginner in android development. I came by this error, when i try to set the text using `".setText()"` for a text view it says it may produce null pointer exception. I am stuck and don't know what to do!
Please please please Help Me Out guys!

Thanks in advance!!!

```
private void runTimer()
    {

     final TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_time);
     final Handler handler =new Handler();

    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override

        public void run() {
                int hours = seconds/3600;
                int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
                int secs = seconds%60;
                String time = String.format(Locale.US,"%d:%02d:%02d",
                        hours, minutes, secs);
                timeView.setText(time);//this is where i am getting the warning!
                if (running) {
                    seconds++;
                }
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: That warning is **not a Big Deal**. Don't get stuck, just go ahead it will not produce nullpointer if you have the TextView `display_time` in xml..!!

Comment: where did you place that part of code? It must be inside the activity where the xml layout file is set as contentView.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you call runTimmer() after setContentView or if in fragment in onViewCreated()
2. Make sure id: display_time is actually the real id of the TextView you want to use, check the xml file.
3. Only the Ui Thread can make changes to the views, so you need to call `runOnUiThread(new Runnable());`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could wrap a check around it as below, for the peace of mind.

```
private void runTimer()
{

    final TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_time);
    final Handler handler =new Handler();

    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override

        public void run() {
            int hours = seconds/3600;
            int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
            int secs = seconds%60;
            String time = String.format(Locale.US,"%d:%02d:%02d",
                    hours, minutes, secs);
            if (timeView != null) {
                timeView.setText(time);//this is where i am getting the warning!
            }
            if (running) {
                seconds++;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }
    });

}
```

In the event that `timeView` is null for any reason (your activity ended?), no NPE will be thrown.

Comment: Is it common approach?

Answer (score 1):

Check `R.id.display_time` if it is pointing to the `TextView` in the same layout. as your activity.